# Excel Macro to Copy Down Formulas until Data Ends

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where, every month, I will paste a dataset. In a different sheet, I have formulas that will modifying that data in different ways. Because the dataset will be different sizes, I want the macro to copy down the formula on the Summary Sheet only as far as the data exists on the Data Sheet.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim Last As Long

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "DataSource!A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:AN3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:AN" & LR)
            
End Sub
```

The source table will vary by number of rows, but the columns in question will always run from A to BF. The formulas on the Summary tab run from A to AN.

Thanks!

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSource")`, `Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, `End With`. then change `LR` to `Last`.